# Python/Pandas - Manipulating strings in a column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
index      code
1         432-1
2         424-5
3         098-9
...
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
index      code
1          4321
2          4245
3          0989
...
```

I managed to get the first 3 numbers prior to the hyphen with this code:

```
df['code']=df['code'].astype(str).str[:2]
```

Seems stupid but I'm having a hard time trying to merge that with the last character in a pythonic way. Could someone help?

Comment: Have you tried `df['code'].str.replace("-", "")`?

Comment: Alternatively: `df['code'].astype(str).str[:3] + df['code'].astype(str).str[-1]`.

Comment: I tried @Evert 's suggestion before but didn't work

Comment: @cmaher 's suggestion works fine, thanks

Comment: I think the replace alternative is much better, but I'm surprised my example doesn't work. Perhaps your actual dataframe is more elaborate and causing issues, but the simple example suggested in your code works fine for me. I'm curious what was not working for you then.

Comment: @Evert I'm not sure also, that was my first guess too. I was doing df['code']=df['code'].astype(str).str[:3] + df['code'].astype(str).str[-1] but the result was that it was for some reason disconsidering what was after the "+" and getting only the first three characters (df['code'].astype(str).str[:3])